# Chart has the major grid and labels set on decimal values

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I use a chart component from the .Net library and I plot values from some files. The X axis can contain decimal values (for example from 0.01 to 7.00) and there may be 100 points at random intervals. The chart X axis gets automatically marked 1, 3.15, 4.15, 5.15, 6.15. How can I get round values for the X axis (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)?

I initially tried using `resChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.RoundAxisValues();` but there was no change in the chart appearance because I set indexed values on the X axis.

This is how the chart looks like now. The grid is not aligned with the axis labels.
[image]

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    chart1.Series.Clear();
    chart1.Series.Add("Series0");
    chart1.Series.Add("Series1");
    chart1.Legends.Clear();
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.RoundAxisValues();
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0";
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 1;

    chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    List<Tuple<double, double>> values = new List<Tuple<double, double>>();
    values.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(1.1, 3.6));
    values.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(2.22, 2.8));
    values.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(3.30, 3.8));
    values.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(4.45, 4.2));
    values.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(5.62, 2.7));
    values.Add(new Tuple<double, double>(6.77, 3.1));

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 7;

    foreach (Tuple<double, double> pair in values)
    {
            double xVar = pair.Item1;
            double yVar = pair.Item2;
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(xVar, yVar);
            chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(xVar, yVar / 2.0 + 0.3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting the Interval (to 1) and maybe offset values. If you need a real custom spacing you would have to use CustomLabels. Also make sure to use __numbers__ for the x-values; looks like you didn't do that.. Usually a mistake, especially if you need these numbers. Looks as if you just added formatted strings, which are stuffed into the Labels but otherwise useless..

Comment: If I change the Interval from Auto to 1, I can't see any values for axes, and a forest of vertical black lines. The x-values are set to numbers and I provide double to both X and Y. I didn't use formatted strings for labels, in fact I didn't add anything for labels.

Comment: _The x-values are set to numbers_ Really? Then how come the distance between all grids&labels is the same while the numbers are so different? Can you check in the debugger? Can you show the code that add the dtapoints? Or did you set x-values-are-indexed?

Comment: I set that the X values are indexed. Because sometimes I place multiple series on the chart and it didn't work well if I didn't index them. I didn't provide the code because it is spread over a few functions, plus I edited the properties of the chart. I thought it will be a very easy to answer question, which needs no sample code. I will put it all together and edit my question.

Comment: A Series should only be indexed if the numeric x-values are meaningless, like e.g. a zip code, an ID etc.. - Which may or may not be the case here. - _it didn't work well if I didn't index them._ If you care about the numbers you should fix this issue instead. How didn't it work 'well'? And how are the x-values of the 2nd etc.. series to the 1st one?ralated

Comment: I understand. I actually just fixed my code, because you asked me about the indexing. I was not aware of its role and probably a temporary bug I had in my code prevented me to make the chart work without indexing.

Comment: I lied. It is still bad. If I have the points between 0 to 7, it shows marks at 1.4, 2.8, 4.2, 5.6. I want them to show at 1, 2, 3, ..., 7

Comment: Set the Interval to `1` and keep `RoundAxisValues = true` or set `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0"`...

Comment: I did that, I took another screenshot of the chart and edited the code in my question. It's missing some values on the X axis and the intervals are disproportionate. Never imagined it will be so hard to plot integers on an axis...

Comment: _hard to plot integers on an axis_ Well, you are not plotting integers but doubles and the 'missing' values are omitted because the automatic interval is not an integer but a rounded double. Do set the Interval to 1 !!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do that in the sample code, but I did it in my program. I edited now the sample code and pasted a new image. The grid is not aligned with the labels.

Comment: you found that the Grid has its own Interval (and Offset) properties. You will want to set __both__ Grid and general/datapoint Interval values..: `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;`

Comment: I can't believe  it. It seems to work now! Thanks!